How to fix issue with missing file npm-v6.13.4.zip on installation of node 10.18.0 with nvm 1.2.0?
I try to install node v10.18.0 with nvm but have following issue:
C:\Windows\system32>nvm install 10.18.0
Downloading node.js version 10.18.0 (64-bit)...
Complete
Downloading npm...
Creating C:\Users\ps350027\AppData\Local\Temp\nvm-install-2546143479\temp

Downloading npm version 6.13.4... Complete
Installing npm v6.13.4...
error installing 10.18.0: open C:\Users\ps350027\AppData\Local\Temp\nvm-npm-1000768504\npm-v6.13.4.zip: The system cannot find the file specified.


It looks like it's downloading into one directory and then looking in a different directory for installation.
What can I do in this case?
Is there any file/directory location in need to modify?
By the way: I'm using Windows 10 and CMD is opened as administrator.
In below screenshot:
node and npm are downloaded into the same directory under subdirectory temp. But nvm looks at some other location while installing.


Is there any particular reason why you're trying to install such an obsolete version?

@GuyIncognito Yes, project requirements
